# Correct way to dynamically change axios proxy URL?

Tags: vue.js, axios, electron

I have this code in my main Vue file:

```
export default axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1',
  proxy: {
    '/api/': 'http://127.0.0.1',
    '/w0w/': 'http://192.168.1.12'
  }
})
Vue.prototype.$axios = axios;

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

What is the best practice in regards of changing the target URL of proxy requests going out to `/w0w/` in runtime?

that is - let the user modify these addresses via the UI.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your export to be a method that accepts an URL and call it when you need to update it

```
const createAxios = (proxyURL) => {
 axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1',
  proxy: {
    '/api/': 'http://127.0.0.1',
    '/w0w/': proxyURL || 'http://192.168.1.12'
  }
 })
}

export default createAxios
```

Now you need to call it a bit differently

```
Vue.prototype.$axios = axios(/*or custom proxy url here*/);
```